# I can't Inject class by identifier for interfaces

Tags: nestjs

I guess it's hard to read because I use the translation function to write sentences, sorry.

I am trying to inject a provider based on an interface.
Below is my code.

**storage-base.interface.ts**

```
export interface IStorageBase {
  upload(fileName: string): Promise<string>;
  deleteLocalFile(fileName: string): Promise<void>;
}
```

**blob.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';
import { IStorageBase } from './storage-base.interface';

type BlobDependencies = {
  connectionString: string;
  containerName: string;
};

@Injectable()
export class BlobService implements IStorageBase {
  private readonly blobServiceClient: BlobServiceClient;
  private readonly containerClient: ContainerClient;

  constructor(blobDependencies: BlobDependencies) {
    //Some kind of processing
  }

  upload(filename: string): Promise<string> {
    //Some kind of processing
  }

  deleteLocalFile(filename: string): Promise<void> {
    //Some kind of processing
  }

  private getAbsolutePath(filename: string): string {
    //Some kind of processing
  }
}
```

**core.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BlobService } from './blob.service';

const blobServiceProvider = { provide: 'IStorageBase', useClass: BlobService };

@Module({
  providers: [blobServiceProvider],
  exports: [blobServiceProvider],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

The `Blob` class implements the `IStorageBase` interface.
And `CoreModule` makes providers based on `IStoraegBase` available to other modules.

example:

**video-cut-out.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { VideoCutOutService } from './video-cut-out.service';
import { VideoCutOutController } from './video-cut-out.controller';
import { CoreModule } from '../core/core.module';

@Module({
  imports: [CoreModule],
  providers: [VideoCutOutService],
  controllers: [VideoCutOutController],
  exports: [],
})
export class VideoCutOutModule {}
```

**video-cut-out.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { VideoCutOutRequest, VideoCutOutResponse } from './video-cut-out.model';
import { IStorageBase } from '../core/storage-base.interface';

@Injectable()
export class VideoCutOutService {
  constructor(@Inject('IStorageBase') private _blob: IStorageBase) {}
  async executeAsync(
    videoCutOutRequest: VideoCutOutRequest,
  ): Promise<VideoCutOutResponse> {
    //Some kind of processing
  }
}
```

However, when this is executed, the following error is output.

```
[Nest] 18352   - 2020-03-30 17:04:12   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the IStorageBase (?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the CoreModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If Object is a provider, is it part of the current CoreModule?
- If Object is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within CoreModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Object */ ]
  })
 +47ms
```

I think that interface cannot be injected into "providers" or "imports" of Module Decorator.
How can I resolve the above error and run the program normally?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest is having an issue because in your `BlobService` you have dependencies on `BlobDependencies`, but you don't have those being provided anywhere in your `CoreModule`. Along with that, as it is a custom type and not a class, it gets converted to an `object` at runtime, which is why Nest gives you the error of `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the IStorageBase (?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the CoreModule context.`. The important thing to notice here is that it is talking about `IStorageBase` in the context of `CoreModule`, meaning that `CoreModule` is where the error is. To fix this, provide some sort of dependency for Nest to inject and make sure to add the `@Inject()` decorator, as Nest will not be able to inject generically for `Object`

Comment: I overlooked custom type dependencies!
Solved by registering the custom type in 'core.module.ts' as a custom provider!

Thank you very much.